# files being transmitted with PHP cURL/FTP with zero bytes

Tags: php, curl, file-io, ftp

I have encountered an issue recently where, during periods of high traffic to my application, small CSV files are being sent with cURL/FTP with zero bytes. However, when I view the file on my filesystem I can see that it is definitely not empty and not zero bytes in size.

This is my PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen($bFile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://'.FTP_SERVER .'/'.FTP_DIRECTORY.$file_name);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, FTP_USER.':'.FTP_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($bFile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

I also have some basic error handling in the code where cURL returns an error:

```
if ( curl_error($ch) ) {
    throw new Exception("File could not be sent via FTP: " . curl_error($ch));
}
```

However, I note in this example there is no occasion where the exception is thrown and the code execution continues.

Would there be any reason that I have a, say, a 5Kb CSV file on my filesystem, but the FTP server I am sending the file to has only a zero byte file? Does this point to a transmission issue, possibly caused by high amounts traffic at this time of year?

Comment: Sounds like a real bear to troubleshoot.  Consider adding log points before and after the `curl_exec` call?  Do you have the [FTP extension](http://php.net/book.ftp) installed?  It's more annoying to use, but you might be able to coax better errors out of it.

Comment: Yes, it is an awkward issue to troubleshoot as it is not happening on every file or even all that frequent. It's like 1 file in 500, or more even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention its during high traffic. Is it possible that there is lots or read/write activity on the CSV files you are trying to send? Perhaps its the fopen that actually fails and thus you are sending 0 bytes, but with the correct filename. That would only generate a warning so wont be caught.

Perhaps you should add some logging to the different values you are sending with curl, like `filesize($bFile)` and `$fp`

Comment: The CSV files are created, written to and then deleted by the one script (the same one that sends it), so I don't think there will be a lot of read/write activity on the file. So logging around the file size of the file is a good point, I think I will need to do that.

Comment: I have added in a check like this `if (filesize($bFile) == false or filesize($bFile) == '0') {` and `if ($fp === false) {` to check if `fopen` is failing, so we'll see if that can narrow down the issue to me sending empty files.